# Inject vs Injectable vs Custom Providers

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

I’m having difficulty trying to figure out when to use what.  I understand DI and have done this for years, but within NestJS it seems like there are things missing from the docs that would help me understand why some assigned properties go missing from an injected item.

We have a logger that gets injected via a custom provider.

From looking at the docs, they'll add `@Inject` during the constructor area, but if I'm injecting via a custom provider, why use `@Inject`?

Equally, why use `@Injectable` if we have custom providers handling all the injection setup for the module?

Where the question comes up is that filename is getting lost among other injected services where sometimes when the logger gets executed in one service, the filename is the same, while other times the service being different, it will retain the filename from the ctor name of a different service.

Anyway, I don't understand why to use one set up over another.

Update: I found we follow the LifeCycle on some Services, but I find the logger doesn't retain at the time of execution.

```
//custom-provider
export ClientProvider = {
   provide: Client,
   userFactory: (logger: Logger): Client => {
        return new Client(logger);
   },
   inject: [Logger.getToken()]
};

//client
export class Client{
    private readonly logger;
    constructor(logger:Logger){
        this.logger = logger;
        if (this.logger) this.logger.fileName = this.constructor.name;
    }
}

//logger
export class Logger {
    static getToken(): string { return 'the-token-key'; }
    private filename: string;

    constructor(filename: string){
        this.filename = filename;
    }
}

//cat-service
export class CatService implements OnModuleInit {
    private readonly logger;
    constructor(@Inject(Logger.getToken()) private logger:Logger){
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    onModuleInit() {
       if (this.logger) this.logger.fileName = this.constructor.name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, high level, Nest naturally uses metadata reflected from Typescript to know what to bind and where. Normally, this metadata is things like Class Names that exist at runtime, which is why you cannot use interfaces.

`@Injectable()` tells Nest that it should look for the metadata provided in this class's constructor and find the correct providers. This is how Nest does most of the DI, as mentioned before.

`@Inject()` tells Nest, "Hey, I know this says it is a `Logger` class, but really inject the provider with the injection token I tell you", which is useful for things like using specific instances of, say, a  Logger class.

With a custom provider, `@Injectable()` is not necessary if you use a factory, as you have shown, but it would be if you were to use a class instead, because factories return the instance of the value to be provided, whereas with `useClass` you are returning a class definition that Nest will need to instantiate.

The only reason I could see your filename being overwritten is that providers are singleton scope between modules, but if the same provider is in the `providers` array then it should be a new instance each time, so maybe something with that is acting a little wonky

Comment: Thanks @Jay! I was thinking about it more, and I forgot about the Singleton. Also, thank you for the explanation, it really helped me. Let me ask you this: are tokens simply named configurations? For example, if you have multiple setups with the same class, the token helps you keep the unique for injection?

Comment: That's definitely a good way to look at it. For a system I'm currently building, I have a custom decorator that can take in a parameter. This decorator is essentially a wrapper around Nest's `@Inject()` decorator, that helps with creating the correct injection token. This token is created both by the decorator, and by the dynamic module's `forFeature()` function, to ensure that the provider token is correctly created for the current context.